# Insert default value into ms access table from code

Tags: ms-access-2007

I want to insert OfficerID of the officer currently logged in as a default value into the table T_FileCases.

Already in the login form I have a field that holds officer's name (UserName) when they are logged in successfully but when this happens I also want to automatically insert their OfficerID into the table T_FileCases automatically, instead of using a combo box for selecting officers name when creating a new case.

```
Me.Hold_User_ID = Nz(DLookup("OfficerID", "Table_Officers", "Names='" & Me.UserName & "' and NRC='" & Me.PWD & "'"), -1)
    ' check to see if we have a good login
    If Me.Hold_User_ID = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Sorry boss, you typed invalid username or password.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' load the users access level into the holder form field
        Me.hold_level = DLookup("Access_Level", "Table_Officers", "Names='" & Me.UserName & "' and NRC='" & Me.PWD & "'")

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Before Insert event of the data entry form you could create an event procedure to check for the UserID and populate the field with the appropriate value.

This would require that the UserID is able to be retrieved at this point, either by keeping the login form hidden in the background or by assigning the value from the login form to a Global variable at the point of validation.

Comment: Is it like this:  Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.txtCaseID.Value >= 1 Then
INSERT INTO T_Cases (OfficerID) values Forms.F_FileCases!txtCaseID;
End If
End Sub